# AWS Cognito User Pools for B2B szenario

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, serverless, aws-appsync

I'm developing atm a B2B scenario on AWS. In this szenario, a company creates an organization and invite their employees there and only this “Organization members” can see the content there, for example in an S3 Bucket. I'm using Cognito User Pool to authenticate the users. Do someone know if can map such a corporate case also with Cognito and how? I suppose This "Role Management" should be dynamically handled in the code. At the moment I'm using serverless with Lambda, API Gateway, DynamoDB, and S3 but I'm planning to use Appsync.

Thank you for every help :-)

Comment: Sounds like a multi-tenanted scenario. Do you plan on having one codebase?

Comment: Yes, actually what I want is that a company can register and invite their employees. All employees can access (read, write) to this s3 bucket folder. Another company has only access to another s3 bucket folder.